# Duplicate symbol error when using Dropbox SDK with ShareKit SDK

Tags: ios, sharekit, dropbox-api

I am getting the following error when I try to use the app which already has Dropbox SDK in it and ShareKit added. Is this a known issue, and is there a solution.

Thanks !

duplicate symbol _EstimateBas64DecodedDataSize in [App Path]/DropboxSDK.framework/DropboxSDK

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem and deleted the Base64Transcoder files without removing references. Somehow, it works now!